# Distributions without finite moments

Tags: probability, statistics, actuarial-science

A statistician colleague of mine posed a question to me regarding certain distributions used in loss models. Naturally occurring distributions, such as inverse Pareto, do not have finite moments. But naturally occurring questions within actuarial science, such as those involving expected shortfall, involve moments or moments of right tails. Of course, this can be infinite.

When one is modeling with a distribution that has infinite first or second moment, and one has practical questions where infinite first or second moment provides some obstruction, is there some remediation? Is there some common practice for reaching meaningful answers while circumventing the lack of moments?

Comment: There are lots of distribution of practical importence which don't have moments. One such class is the class of stable distributions widely used in Mathematical Finance. These are handled using characteristic functions.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "These are handled using characteristic functions"? Possibly with a specific question whose answer is obstructed by a lack of moments and how the characteristic function is used to circumvent this obstruction. I am not an actuary, so I am somewhat unfamiliar with the specific questions one in that field may want to answer.

Comment: For example if you want to study sample path properties of stable processes you cannot use the method used for Brownian motion because second moments don't exist. But there is vast literature on stable processes and the proofs of theorems on these  are based on the so-called Levy -Khinchine representation of infinitely divisible distributions; this representation describes the form of the characteristic function.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking as a non-life actuary, while we often use distributions without finite moments (such as a Pareto with $\alpha \leq 1$), we never do so on an *unlimited* basis. Agreed, that way lies madness. What we are often tasked to do is find the loss in a layer, or the loss subject to some cap. The cap may be the entire surplus of the company, although it is more often a percentage when dealing with company-wide ERM issues. Regardless, all distributions have finite moments if you truncate or even censor them from above. That makes the math and simulations work.